# Response to selection criteria regarding health and wellbeing

Tags: postdocs, job-search

I am prepareing response to answer selection criteria for a academic job in a university in Australia where the last question is
**Enthusiasm for addressing research questions relevant to human health and wellbeing.**

Anyone please tell me the points how should I write that?

Comment: What's your field?

Comment: Engineering, Machine Learning, AI

Comment: I don't know whether your concern includes ambiguity, but I first thought it was asking about **your** health and wellbeing in being able to carry out your desired research in an enthusiastic manner! But not only is this probably illegal in Australia, the actual wording does fit the intended meaning better than my initial misreading. I think a better word than "Enthusiasm" could have been used at the beginning -- maybe "Concern". That said, maybe some of the more general advice for writing a [diversity statement](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/60094/49593) could be useful.

Comment: Thats the question in the selection criteria starts with enthusiasm. I cant change that word. I dont think I can fit the diversity in this question. Its not related to any technical answer its a general question.

Comment: I assumed you copied the exact wording, so my comments about the use of "Enthusiasm" pertain to the source wording (which I think could have been better worded), not to you. Character limitations prevented me from being more explicit about this part -- I think I had 2 or 3 characters left, and this was after some extensive revisions of my comment. As for my mention of diversity statements, I only mean it's related in a general way. In the same way one might discuss past experiences and future plans in the context of diversity issues, you could do the same for human health and wellbeing.

Answer (score 2):

The existence of such a question implies to me that the university, or perhaps just the department, has made some commitment to advancing human health and wellbeing. Perhaps this is a shared goal of many (most?) of the existing faculty.

The question may or may not be one that will be decisive in choosing a candidate. But it seems to be asking whether your personal goals are in alignment with that shared goal.

Perhaps you have thought of this sort of thing in the past, and perhaps your natural inclination is to support it. But it is also possible that you've never considered it and think it is irrelevant. I doubt that anyone would be likely to actively oppose it, however.

But, I always suggest that you answer honestly. Even if your answer is just "I'll have to think about that for a while as the question hasn't come up before" it could be enough. Answering "Stupid, Stupid, STUPID." won't get you the job, I think. And if that is, in fact, your first thought, then you might not be a good fit with the others, even if you get the job.

I find the question thought provoking, if nothing else. In some fields, it is an important question also - medical fields, for example. In CS and mathematics it is a bit more speculative.

But even in AI, a commitment to "do no harm" is worth the effort it takes. Some machine learning algorithms have proven problematic in the recent past, having been trained on a too-narrow or even racist base.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a poorly-constructed question, because there are only three possible answers.

- **My past work demonstrates my enthusiasm.** I've previously published these papers, these hobbies, these courses, etc. with the specific goal of using AI to improve human health/wellbeing. Nice if you actually do have evidence of this passion, but most applicants (even qualified ones) will not.
- **I have no concrete evidence, but I nonetheless claim to have this enthusiasm.** Virtually all students will give this answer. It's hard to know how much pandering or grandiose word-smithing is appropriate (though most students do too much, and the result is cringe-worthy).
- **My interest is in X; to the extent that we can study human health with X, I am enthusiastic about it.** I personally would respect you for being honest, but presumably they wouldn't have asked the question if "little/no enthusiasm" were the correct answer. So, it's important to phrase this answer carefully.

Anyway, back to your question....

> how should I write that?

- If you actually have evidence of this passion you should discuss it. Weak evidence (i.e., hobbies) is okay, but don't exaggerate.
- Otherwise, you can state your enthusiasm without providing evidence. But, I would try to give an honest and straightforward answer -- recall that this is a professional document addressed to a stranger. Also, there is no need to max out the word count.